# Is there any way possible to extract data after writing to outputstream?

Tags: java

I am trying to create several sockets and connecting it with a single client using socket programming. Every time a client tries to communicate with server a new socket gets created and messages can be sent but the problem comes when i try to pass more than one message through server. the first message gets sent and the for the rest, i face stream corrupted exceptions.Following is my code for the class that tries to read object from output stream.

Comment: do you have some source to share?

Comment: `Following is my code`: Nothing here, scrolled down the bottom of the page too :)

Comment: I can feel it though...